# Find all non-matching items, based on an input parameter, in an array and return it as a new array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of company names and I want to see if they match a certain value.

In fact, I want a list of all non-matching values. Something like this:

```
"One or more companies: [company1], [company2] are not equal to [checkCompany]
```

Example:

```
checkCompany = "GM"
companies = ["GM", "GM", "Ford"]
```

In this case there would only be one company not equal to "GM" but there could be more than one.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your attempts and the code you've written in the question. Should the match be case-sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

This function should simply work, its arguments are the companies array and the *checkCompanies* string that you want to check against.

The function then returns *tempList* which includes all the values that do not match with *checkCompanies* string.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public ArrayList<String> checkList(ArrayList<String> companies, String checkCompany) {
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < companies.size(); i++) {
        if(!companies.get(i).equals(checkCompany)) {
            tempList.add(companies.get(i));
        }
    }

    return tempList;
```

All you would then have to do is format the return to give you the string you want to output!

Answer (score -1):

```
    checkCompany = "GM"
    companies = ["GM", "GM", "Ford"]
    nonMatchedCompanies = list()
    for(String company : companies){
        if(!company.contains(checkCompany)
            nonMatchedCompanies.add(company)
    }
```

`nonMatchedCompanies` is the result which will contain all not matched companies from the list. This will check if the checkCompany is part of company name.

Comment: Java already has many great containers for just this 'sort' of problem. For example in this case, "Set".